# Is Spring Compatible with Serverless Computing

Tags: spring, aws-lambda, serverless

I've seen this post here: https://dzone.com/articles/making-spring-boot-application-run-serverless-with which gives an example of how to use Spring in a Serverless scenario, but I believe that this still involves creating the Spring context, an expensive thing to do every time a request comes in. And I am wondering if Spring, but also the traditional web application frameworks are even truely compatible with the severless model, as they all tend to assume the server is only going to initialise on start, and then not again till the server is restarted, as opposed to being immediately ready to handle a request and not needing to initialize a Spring context for instance. So then these frameworks tend to do allot of stuff in the start up phase, which is not good I believe when you don't have a server per-say, and you effectively need to start up every time your would call what would be a lambda in AWS.

So my question is are these traditional web frameworks, such as Spring, which perform allot of compute when starting up still applicable in the Serverless model, for instance: AWS lambda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring can indeed be applicable with the Serverless model, but as you suggest, IMHO it is not suitable for all use cases.

For the reasons that you mention (comparatively long start up times for a "cold" Lambda), I would advise against using Spring when implementing a web app that is deployed to an AWS Lambda function behind an API Gateway as the response times will suffer.

However, there are scenarios when the long start up time of a JVM based function handler implementation in a cold AWS Lambda function is less of a headache and where you may consider this option. One example is as a consumer of a Kinesis stream. The cold start will still be as bad as in the previous case, but if you have a steady stream of events the cold start will only occur once per shard. Another difference is that when using Kinesis you have already chosen an asynchronous application flow. In other words, the event producer can continue its work as soon as the event has been put on the stream without waiting for the event to be processed.

Comment: Just to add that suppose you have your services already built using Spring boot and you would like to expose single service or micro-services then AWS lambda can be great choice here and can save you alot against deploying it on the environment.

Answer (score 2):

There are some Spring sub-projects that try to deal with this scenario, like Spring Cloud Function:
https://spring.io/blog/2017/07/05/introducing-spring-cloud-function

```
The deployment profiles even extend into the realm of Serverless (a.k.a. Functions-as-a-Service) providers, such as AWS Lambda and Apache OpenWhisk (as well as Azure Functions and Google Cloud Functions once they provide support for Java)
```

However, context initialization is still needed, so I guess is up to the developer to make it as small as possible to guarantee a quick startup.

*EDIT*: Today, I was on a talk given by [Dave Syer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1259109/dave-syer) in the Spring I/O Conference, and he presented some solutions to make Spring Boot more suitable for serveless computing:

- Spring Boot Mini Applications: They are SB application but with reduced contexts:
  https://github.com/dsyer/spring-boot-thin-launcher
- Spring Boot thin launcher:
  https://github.com/dsyer/spring-boot-thin-launcher
- Some benchmarks on how long does it take to launch several configurations:
  https://github.com/dsyer/spring-boot-startup-bench